# Notify Threads When Counter Changes

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to design a class as a Code Kata for myself that has a value property that can be set, and the class can issue ValueListener instances. The idea is that there is one instance of ValueHolder with many client threads accessing it concurrently. Each client thread has requested a ValueWatcher and has called waitForValue().

What I am really struggling with is what condition I should use on the while loop around the wait() to avoid spurious notifications (i.e. value hasn't changed). I can see that this design may make it possible of ValueWatcher instances to miss updates, but am less worried about that at this stage.

Would appreciate any guidance on offer!

```
public class ValueHolder {

  private int value = 0;
  private final Object monitor = new Object();

  public void setValue(int value) {
    synchronized(monitor) {
      this.value = value;
      monitor.notifyAll();
    }
  }

  ValueWatcher createChangeWatcher() {
    return new ValueWatcher();
  }

  private class ValueWatcher {
    public int waitForValue() {
      synchronized(monitor) {
        while (==== ??? =====) {
          monitor.wait();
          return value;
        }
      }
    }
  }     
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing spurious notifications?  If only the updater calls `notify` or `notifyall` then I don't see how you would be.

Comment: Could be that the `setValue` call should only `notify` others if the `value` has actually changed?  Right now it could be updated with the same value and everyone gets notified.  Is that what you want?

Comment: I don't see why there is a need for a `while` loop at all.

Comment: @Gray - I am not seeing spurious wake-ups, but these are entirely possible depending on Java/OS implementation (although rare). I want to design correctly.

Comment: @Scruffers What makes you think these are possible? I might be missing something but I fail to see how it's possible unless there's another piece of code that calls `notifyAll()` on the same lock object.

Comment: @biziclop - Although I am inclined to agree with you and that is some of my problem, the Java documentation states - "Always invoke wait inside a loop that tests for the condition being waited for. Don't assume that the interrupt was for the particular condition you were waiting for, or that the condition is still true."

Comment: I see what you mean now. If you need all the threads to wake up on every change and only then, it's not a simple task. You need several locks and semaphores and even then you're not guaranteed to read the correct `value`

Comment: @biziclop - a "spurious wakeup" is permitted to occur, in general, as a concession to the underlying platform semantics. Please see the following Oracle documentation for [concurrent.locks.Condition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) which I would consider authoritative since was written by Doug Lea :)

Comment: @@biziclop It has not necessarily something to do with the OS/JVM, it's a.. well "hardware feature". The same is true for say `pthread_cond_wait` so it's nothing special to java. There's just no way to avoid this problem efficiently on some architectures so it's left to the programmer. Also afaik at least on linux if a process receives a signal the kernel will return abruptely as well.

Comment: @Voo I suspect that signals will result in `InterruptedException`s, which is a separate issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting problem.  Here's one solution off the top of my head.  Have a version number along with the value that is being changed.  Whenever the value is updated, the version number is also incremented so the `ValueWatcher` objects can then check to see if the version went up meaning a change has happened.

**Edit:**
I initially had an `AtomicLong` but I am stealing the idea of a wrapper object from @John Vint.

```
private final VersionValue versionValue = new VersionValue();

public void setValue(int value) {
    synchronized (monitor) {
       versionValue.value = value;
       versionValue.version++;
       monitor.notifyAll();
    }
}

 private class ValueWatcher {
     private long localVersion = 0;
     public int waitForValue() {
         synchronized (monitor) {
             while (true) {
                 if (localVersion < versionValue.version) {
                     // NOTE: the value might have been set twice here
                     localVersion = versionValue.version;
                     return versionValue.value;
                 }
                 monitor.wait();
             }
         }
     }
}

private static class VersionValue {
    int value;
    long version;
}
```

---

Also, although spurious wakeups are possible it is important to remember that the text:

> Always invoke wait inside a loop that tests for the condition being waited for. Don't assume that the interrupt was for the particular condition you were waiting for, or that the condition is still true.

Is more about race conditions and producer/consumer models than spurious wakeups.  See [my page here about that](http://256.com/gray/docs/misc/producer_consumer_race_conditions/).

Comment: To do that without races you would have to combine the version number with the value in a single atomic type (e.g: `AtomicLong versionedValue = value | (long) version << 0xffff`.

Comment: Oh I see it.  I need to move my synchronized outside the while. Right.  Thanks @ninjalj.

Comment: race: you get localCounter for update `n` and return `value` of update `n+1`. Next time you get `localCounter` for update `n+1` and return an unchanged `value`

Comment: I widened the `synchronized` block @ninjalj.   I set the `localCounter` to be the value of the `globalCounter`.  The `value` that gets returned is always the latest one.  Next time through `localCounter` = `n+1` so nothing is returned.

Comment: and as you can see it's complicated code and it took you several attempts to get it "right". So I advocate using `wait` and `notify` the way they are usually used.

Comment: How is this using `wait` and `notify` incorrectly?  Spurious wakeups may not be too common but they do happen and need to be at least considered in the design.

Comment: @ninjalj The complication does not come from incorrect use of `wait` and `notify`. It comes from the rather special requirement that every single value change has to trigger one and only one response. In real life this very rarely is the case, so most wait/notify constructions are a lot simpler.

Comment: @Gray: Is not technically incorrect (now). It just doesn't feel right (too complicated and error-prone. I like John Vint's solution more, but I still think you're reading too much into the OP's question.

Comment: @biziclop: from the question: _I can see that this design may make it possible of ValueWatcher instances to miss updates, but am less worried about that at this stage._

Comment: @ninjalj. Yeah John's solution with a wrapping object is good but I'd rather do a version number than a timestamp.  I'm not sure what I'm doing that excessive however.  Best of luck dude.

Answer (score 2):

All you really care about is if the value changed after you enter the method and its synchronized block.  So take a timestamps of the last time a value has been changed and only continue when the last updated timestamp > then when you entered.

```
    private final StampedValue stamped = new StampedValue();

    public void setValue(int value) {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            this.stamped.value = value;
            this.stamped.lastUpdated = System.currentTimeMillis();
            monitor.notifyAll();
        }
    }
    private class ValueWatcher {

        public int waitForValue() { 
          synchronized(monitor) {
               long enteredOn = System.currentTimeMillis();    
               while (enteredOn > stamped.lastUpdated) {
                   monitor.wait();
               }
               return stamped.value;
          }
        }
    }
    private class StampedValue {
        long lastUpdated = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int value;
    }
```

Comment: There's some problems in the `while` loop @John.  I think you want the return outside of it maybe?

Comment: Also, the first time through it is likely that if the value has not been set, the `waitForValue()` will return 0 right off the bat because `enteredOn` is now and `lastUpdated` is 0.

Comment: @Gray Yea copy and paste failed me

Comment: I stole your idea for a wrapper object @John.  +1 for it.

Comment: Hey dude.  What happened to your comments to my other question?  You should post an answer to that question with them because they were spot on.

Answer (score 1):

What about each listener having a `BlockingQueue` which it gives to the value-setting thread as part of its registration as a listener? Then, when the value is changed, the value-setting thread simply loops over each of those queues, giving it the new value. You may want to use `BlockingQueue.offer` in that loop, so that if one thread isn't yet ready to receive the new value, it won't stop other threads from receiving it.

This may not be the most efficient approach, but it's simple, and the concurrent structure (ie the hard part) is well-tested and maintained for you. And it's not that inefficient, either.

Answer (score 0):

```
private class ValueWatcher {
  private int oldValue = 0;

  public int waitForValue() {
    synchronized(monitor) {
      while (value == oldValue) {
        monitor.wait();
      }
      oldValue = value
      return oldValue;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There's a race here in case the value changes and then is changed back.

Comment: That has one obvious problem: If we set the value to the existing value (ie `newVal == oldVal`)we lose an update. [ABA problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem)

Comment: Also I think there's a bug there that would cause an infinite loop.  I think you want to say `if (oldValue != value) { oldValue = value ; break }`

Comment: @Voo: I contend that `value` should have some meaningful value, which is what the watchers should be interested in. Bistate booleans don't qualify, unless you run 2 threads in lockstep.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ValueHolder {

    private final Object monitor = new Object();
    private LinkedList<WeakReference<ValueWatcher>> waiters = new LinkedList<WeakReference<ValueWatcher>>();

    public void setValue(int value) {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            Iterator<WeakReference<ValueWatcher>> it = waiters.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                WeakReference<ValueWatcher> ref = it.next();
                if (ref.get() == null)
                    it.remove();
                else
                    ref.get().waitingList.add(value);
            }
            monitor.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    ValueWatcher createChangeWatcher() {
        ValueWatcher ret = new ValueWatcher();
        synchronized( monitor ) {
            waiters.add(new WeakReference<ValueWatcher>(ret));
        }
        return ret;
    }

    private class ValueWatcher {

        private Queue<Integer> waitingList = new LinkedList<Integer>();

        public int waitForValue() {
            synchronized (monitor) {
                while (waitingList.isEmpty()) {
                    monitor.wait();
                }
                return waitingList.poll();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is that you keep track of who's waiting and each watcher has a queue of values that have been set since the last invocation of `waitForValue()`. This removes the need to store `value` in `ValueHolder`, which is a good thing as by the time a `ValueWatcher` wakes up, that could have changed several times. The drawback of this method is that as you can see is that creating new watchers will block until the monitor is free.