# Is there a way to wait for the change on an atomic integer

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic

Is there a way to wait on an `AtomicInteger` so that I don't have to keep sleeping my current thread and keep checking on the `AtomicInteger` like this

```
while(atomicInt.get() >= 0) {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
}
```

I know there is such a thing as a `CountDownLatch` but that only allows me to decrement I also need it to be able to increment

Further BackStory - 
I have a loop creating threads and I need to wait on one of the threads execution to finish before creating a new thread. I however am using an `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads)` and the only way to wait on it seems to be to call the shutdown method await termination and then create a new threadPool so instead I was using an atomic integer to keep track of how many threads were running and/or on the queue so that when that number decreased I could continue with the loop.

Comment: The short answer is no.  Can you edit your question and explain a bit more _why_ you want this?  There may be other alternatives.

Comment: why not use WaitForSingleObject for waiting . Creating a while loop to wait is a terrible idea.

Comment: Waiting on an atomic object completely defeats the purpose of a wait-free algorithm.  You're doing it wrong.

Comment: Actually, [`Semaphore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) looks more appropriate here.

Comment: Could you explain your scenario (the why). I think there can't be a useful advice without the necessary information.

Comment: A similar question and subsequent answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592992/notify-threads-when-counter-changes

Answer (score 7):

[`Semaphore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) looks like it might be closer to what you're looking for, actually -- it lets you wait until one or more "permits" is available.  `AtomicInteger` isn't meant to be used how you're using it.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you really want is to process some event. That event could in turn increment an integer. Take a peek at the [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

> A Queue that additionally supports operations that wait for the queue to become non-empty when retrieving an element, and wait for space to become available in the queue when storing an element.

The code could look something like...

```
MyEvent incrementEvent = queue.take(); //blocks until an event is added to the queue
// increment int and do logic here
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a closer match to what you want is a [Phaser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html).  My rough understanding is that its a bit like an incrementing counter where you can block until the number is incremented.

```
// This constructor one party (so it expects one advance per phase).
Phaser phaser = new Phaser(1);
try {
  // This will timeout as phase 0 hasn't arrived yet.
  phaser.awaitAdvanceInterruptibly(0, 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  fail();
}
catch (TimeoutException expected) {
}

// Arrive phase 0
phaser.arrive();
phaser.awaitAdvance(0);
try {
  // Phase 1 will timeout..
  phaser.awaitAdvanceInterruptibly(1, 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  fail();
}
catch (TimeoutException expected) {
}

// Arrive phase 1
phaser.arrive();
phaser.awaitAdvance(0);
phaser.awaitAdvance(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Executors API, the right way to wait for task complete is using the Future API. Sample code is show below:

```
Future<?> future = threadPool.submit(task);
future.get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution with **CompletableFuture**

Create CompletableFuture accessible by both threads thread1, thread2

```
private CompletableFuture<Integer> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
```

Wait for value in thread1 (or multiple threads)

```
Integer value = future.join();
```

Calculate value in thread2 and complete future

```
if (!future.isDone()) future.complete(calculatedValue);
```